# Split string based on string length in dotliquid

Tags: azure-logic-apps, dotliquid

I have a scenario where I need to split a string say "VIP tickets John Smith concert today at 4pm and later dinner" into parts where each part is upto 35 chars long. I can see for and slice but this has to be done in a loop to create following json

```
{
   "Informations": [
      {
         "Information": "VIP tickets John Smith concert toda"
      },
      {
         "Information": "y at 4pm and later dinner"
      }
   ]
}
```

how should I slice it? I am trying to write liquid transformation for logic app

```
{
   "Informations": [
      {
         "Information": "VIP tickets John Smith concert toda"
      },
      {
         "Information": "y at 4pm and later dinner"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: above is the output, just use any input with string > 35 chars.

Answer (score 0):

Using Slice expression and compose action, you can split string into multiple words and form the Json. Below are steps I followed,

- Designer of logic app can be shown below,
  [image]
- In Initialize variable action, Initialized string variable with value "VIP tickets John Smith concert today at 4pm and later dinner"
  [image]
- In second Initialize variable action, splitting string variable with expression **slice(variables('string var'),0,35)**. This will split string into another string with length of 35.
  [image]
- In third Initialize variable action, splitting string variable with expression

**slice(variables('string var'),35,70)**.This will split string into another string with length of 35.
[image]

- In compose action forming array with above two sliced strings,
  [image]
- Next taken loop and passing input from compose output. Using another compose action in loop as shown below,
  [image]
- At last using another compose action to form required json as show below,
  [image]
- Below is output of logic app,
  [image]

Output of Initialize variable 2&3

[image]

Output of last compose action,

[image]

Comment: your images not visible, please add them again. Are you trying to do splitting in logic apps? That wont be my option at all.

Comment: Images are provided clearly. Kindly check by clearing cache and other system.
Also if you are not trying to do it in logic app, you need it from dot liquid?
If so kindly edit question and remove azure logic apps tag as it represents you need it in logicapps.